# vscode shows typescript related problems in jsconfig.json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, configuration

I set up a normal create-react-app project and add jsconfig.json to the root directory. But it shows the error which is typescript related.
[image: problems in Vscode terminal]
Here is the jsconfig.json file

[image: jsconfig.json configurations]

Folder structure

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Prakhil

Comment: @Supercool. I think It is not the problem with the exclude property, I've confirmed it.
The documentation says, If IntelliSense is slow, add folders to your exclude list

Comment: I've added the same jsconfig.json to my CRA and no problem at all.

Answer (score 12):

Open the settings.json file, add the below line and then save.

```
 "json.schemas": [
      { 
        "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/jsconfig" 
      }
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: I have this exact problem with my nuxt app, Any suggestions?

Comment: Didn't it work after adding the line on to settings.json? You may have to restart the vscode to get things effective.

Comment: Turns out it was webpack bundle that made the code crush, after removing it, the app works as expected

Comment: I had the same error and tried the above. Restarted VS code and it **did not work**.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error and solved it by changing the extension of the jsconfig.json file to jsconfig.json**c**