# Cannot find type definition file for 'mathjs'

Tags: visual-studio-code, mathjs

I have a new install of VSCode on Windows 11.

I open a previous project and create a `hello_world.js` file. The contents of the hello world are simply:

```js
console.log('hello world');
```

In my `jsconfig.json` I have this error message:

> ```
> Cannot find type definition file for 'mathjs'.
>   The file is in the program because:
>     Entry point for implicit type library 'mathjs'
>
> JSON schema for a JavaScript project using TypeScript tooling
> ```

I have `mathjs` in the `node_modules` folder.

This is the contents of the `jsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "target": "ES2020",
        "jsx": "react",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

I also include the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/mathjs": "^9.4.2",
    "mathjs": "^11.8.0",
    "type": "module"
  }
}
```

I have seen this answer and tried the solutions with no success:
[Seeing unknown typescript error in JSConfig.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525778/seeing-unknown-typescript-error-in-jsconfig-json-file)

So I am totally stuck.
What does this mean and how can I safely remove the error?

Comment: show a [mre]. That includes a minimal package.json and output of `npm list mathjs`

Comment: I don't have this issue. You probably need to provide more info to make this reproducible. Ex. what is in your hello_world.js file. What versions of all your relevant tools do you have installed, etc. Out of curiosity, what happens if you just restart VS Code?

Comment: ?? why does your JS file have _Python_ in it? "_`print('hello world')`_" Why are you testing your repro in a _previous_ project? You should be doing it in a fresh one.

Comment: why are you installing `@types/mathjs` when [`mathjs` already publishes its types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjs)? (see the blue "TS" icon)

Comment: @user,  the `package.json` was automatically updated, presumably when i ran the `npm install`...  should i delete this line `"@types/mathjs": "^9.4.2",` ?   ..it seems that deleting this line has no particular effect.

Comment: For above stated reasons, I don't see why you would need that dependency. Yes, delete it and then run `npm install` to update `node_modules/`. Try restarting VS Code for good measure too after you do that. I'm also curious about what happens if you remove the exclusion of `node_modules` from your jsconfig.json file.

Comment: deleted `"@types/mathjs": "^9.4.2"`,   run `npm install`,  also removed `node_modules` from the `jsconfig.json` file.....    no effect. same error persists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It occurred to me to just remove the filename of the `jsconfig.json` file (for the reasons set out below).

I did stumbling upon this and try all the options which did not work, but lead to the above thought:
["internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582 throw err"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800/internal-modules-cjs-loader-js582-throw-err#62740853)

**So what i did was to rename this file from `jsconfig.json` to `__jsconfig.json` and the error was removed.**

Ultimately (although i do not know the exact reason), `vscode` reads this file as per the docs (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig).

For good measure i also changed `package.json` to `__package.json`.